# oracle sql return 0 if count is null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables `TT_RESULT_SUMMARY_TAB` being the parent table and `TT_RESULT_DETAIL_TAB` being the child table. **Primary key** '`UTC_END_TIME`' of `TT_RESULT_SUMMARY_TAB`  being the **foreign key** of `TT_RESULT_DETAIL_TAB`.
Only if a certain day has **errors** then error information will be inserted to `TT_RESULT_DETAIL_TAB`.Even if no errors found relevant information will be inserted to parent table `TT_RESULT_SUMMARY_TAB` everyday,though `TT_RESULT_DETAIL_TAB` has no error information for the day.

What I'm attempting is to figure out what total number of errors for all the days in the parent table `TT_RESULT_SUMMARY_TAB`

say 2016/11/30 has a total of 1000 errors
and 2016/12/01 has total of zero errors

```
+----------------------+------------+
|total_number_of_errors| GivenDay   |
+----------------------+------------+
|        1000          | 2016/11/30 |        
|           0          | 2016/12/01 |
+----------------------+------------+
```

here's what I tried on oracle developer

```
SELECT NVL(count(TEST_NAME),0)
AS total_number_of_errors,to_char(UTC_END_TIME, 'yyyy,mm,dd')
As GivenDay from TT_RESULT_DETAIL_TAB group by UTC_END_TIME Order by UTC_END_TIME Desc
```

But I've no information on 2016/12/01 saying 0.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "partition outer join" (look it up on Google).
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25555/tdpdw_sql.htm#TDPDW007

You need to build a table, view or subquery with all the individual days for the interval of interest. Then you do an OUTER join to your existing query, and use `coalesce(total_number_of_values, 0)` to get 0 rather than null for dates that are not present in the errors table.

For example:

```
select nvl(t.total_number_of_errors, 0) as total_number_of_errors, d.dt as givenday
from   your_query t right outer join
       ( select to_date('2016/11/30', 'yyyy/mm/dd' dt from dual union all
         select to_date('2016/12/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd' from dual
       ) d
        on t.error_date = d.dt;
```

There are more efficient ways to build the "all-dates-in-the-interval" subquery (using `CONECT BY LEVEL <= ...`) - not covering it here since it's really a separate question.